# Trace of Gamma Matrices

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-matrices, trace

If I have:

$Tr(\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\alpha}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\beta}\gamma^{\rho}\gamma^{\gamma}\gamma^{\sigma}\gamma^{\delta})$

and I want to get it re-ordered like

$Tr(\gamma^{\alpha}\gamma^{\beta}\gamma^{\gamma}\gamma^{\delta}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\rho}\gamma^{\sigma}) + something, $

what should I do? Is there any "fast" trick to compute that?

Comment: That might be more appropriate to the [math.se] .

Comment: Tricks aside, you do know how to utilize the Clifford algebra to move such matrices around, right?

Comment: Yes, I do. I tried to use the anticommutation rule, but too many terms appear. I thought there was a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard work by hand as you have to repeatedly apply the commutators, multiplying the terms. Nowadays everybody uses a computer algebra system for this chore. The most used is [FeynCalc](https://feyncalc.github.io). It took me 5s by typing the following Mathematica code

```
GA[:mu:, :alpha:, :nu:, :beta:, :rho:, :gamma:, :sigma:, :delta:]
DiracOrder[%]
```

to get the following result (it works as simply because you wanted to re-order the indices alphabetically, otherwise it would have taken a few more steps, by first replacing the indices by a,b,c,... for example, then reorder, and then replace back).

$$\begin{align}
\bar{\gamma }^{\mu }&.\bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }\\
&=
\bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\mu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma }+2 \bar{g}^{\alpha  \mu } \bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma }\\
&-2 \bar{g}^{\beta  \mu } \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma }+2 \bar{g}^{\beta  \nu } \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\mu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma }
-4 \bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\beta  \nu } \bar{g}^{\alpha  \mu }\\
&+4 \bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \nu } \bar{g}^{\alpha  \mu }-4 \bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\delta  \nu } \bar{g}^{\alpha  \mu }-8 \bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\beta  \nu } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \rho } \bar{g}^{\alpha  \mu }\\
&+8 \bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\delta  \nu } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \rho } \bar{g}^{\alpha  \mu }-4 \bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \rho } \bar{g}^{\alpha  \mu }+8 \bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\beta  \nu } \bar{g}^{\delta  \rho } \bar{g}^{\alpha  \mu }\\
&-8 \bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \nu } \bar{g}^{\delta  \rho } \bar{g}^{\alpha  \mu }+4 \bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\delta  \rho } \bar{g}^{\alpha  \mu }-8 \bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho } \bar{g}^{\beta  \nu } \bar{g}^{\delta  \sigma } \bar{g}^{\alpha  \mu }\\
&+8 \bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \nu } \bar{g}^{\delta  \sigma } \bar{g}^{\alpha  \mu }+16 \bar{g}^{\beta  \nu } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \rho } \bar{g}^{\delta  \sigma } \bar{g}^{\alpha  \mu }-8 \bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \rho } \bar{g}^{\delta  \sigma } \bar{g}^{\alpha  \mu }\\
&-4 \bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho } \bar{g}^{\delta  \sigma } \bar{g}^{\alpha  \mu }+2 \bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\alpha  \mu }-4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \nu } \bar{g}^{\beta  \mu }\\
&-8 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \rho } \bar{g}^{\delta  \nu } \bar{g}^{\beta  \mu }+4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\delta  \nu } \bar{g}^{\beta  \mu }+4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \rho } \bar{g}^{\beta  \mu }\\
&+8 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \nu } \bar{g}^{\delta  \rho } \bar{g}^{\beta  \mu }-4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\delta  \rho } \bar{g}^{\beta  \mu }-8 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \nu } \bar{g}^{\delta  \sigma } \bar{g}^{\beta  \mu }\\
&+8 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \rho } \bar{g}^{\delta  \sigma } \bar{g}^{\beta  \mu }+4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho } \bar{g}^{\delta  \sigma } \bar{g}^{\beta  \mu }-2 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\beta  \mu }\\
&+4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\beta  \nu } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \mu }-4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\delta  \nu } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \mu }+4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\delta  \rho } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \mu }\\
&+8 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho } \bar{g}^{\beta  \nu } \bar{g}^{\delta  \sigma } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \mu }-4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho } \bar{g}^{\delta  \sigma } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \mu }+2 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \mu }\\
&+4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \nu } \bar{g}^{\delta  \mu }+8 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\beta  \nu } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \rho } \bar{g}^{\delta  \mu }-2 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\delta  \mu }\\
&-4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\delta  \mu } \bar{g}^{\beta  \nu }-4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\mu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \rho } \bar{g}^{\beta  \nu }-8 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \mu } \bar{g}^{\delta  \rho } \bar{g}^{\beta  \nu }\\
&+4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\mu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\delta  \rho } \bar{g}^{\beta  \nu }-8 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\mu } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \rho } \bar{g}^{\delta  \sigma } \bar{g}^{\beta  \nu }-4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\mu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho } \bar{g}^{\delta  \sigma } \bar{g}^{\beta  \nu }\\
&+2 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\mu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\beta  \nu }-4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\mu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\delta  \rho } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \nu }+4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\mu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho } \bar{g}^{\delta  \sigma } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \nu }\\
&-2 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\mu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \nu }+4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\mu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \rho } \bar{g}^{\delta  \nu }+2 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\mu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\delta  \nu }\\
&-4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\delta  \mu } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \rho }-4 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\mu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu } \bar{g}^{\delta  \sigma } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \rho }+2 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\mu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\gamma  \rho }\\
&-2 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\mu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma } \bar{g}^{\delta  \rho }+2 \bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\mu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho } \bar{g}^{\delta  \sigma }+\bar{\gamma }^{\alpha }.\bar{\gamma }^{\beta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\gamma }.\bar{\gamma }^{\delta }.\bar{\gamma }^{\mu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\nu }.\bar{\gamma }^{\rho }.\bar{\gamma }^{\sigma }
\end{align}$$

Comment: Sorry, I had read your question too quickly: I edited my answer to answer your re-ordering.